# TCP router with web front end

Tags: jakarta-ee, gwt, tcp, jca

I need to code a system that reads and write TCP messages. This system reads the messages and routes them to other places (also as TCP messages). 
The management will be done on a web page.

I need help finding solution architecture.

1. Jetty+GWT+ JAVA SE(for TCP handling) The gwt servlet will be used
   for managment
2. Tomcat +gwt TCP handling ??

I know JCA. But this system is small and will not scale, there is no point in using JCA for it.

The routing is affected by the content of the message,
this project is needed in my work place because we need to do a TCP broadcast depending on the message content.

Comment: how it what you want different to `openwrt`?

Comment: IMO this question is too broad so I voted to close. Why do you even want to roll your own router?

Comment: @Jasen he's not talking about routing TCP packets, but TCP streams. Openwrt routes packets.

Comment: @James How about netty? http://netty.io/

Comment: @Malt I plan to use netty, but my question is regarding the architecture of the solution. What will contain the system? Java class which has a main method? Maybe spring bean or an ejb?